# How can I use the Smelte material design library for Svelte.js in an effective, dry, manner?

Tags: javascript, material-design, svelte

I am working on a project with Svelte and the material design library *[Smelte](https://github.com/matyunya/smelte)*. According to the Smelte docs (smeltejs.com), I have to import *every component* in *every file* I want/need to use it, for example, in `src\pages\index.svelte`:

```
<script>
  import Button from "smelte/src/components/Button";
  import Icon from "smelte/src/components/Icon";
</script>
```

Using the lines above in `src\App.svelte` does not work.

This is rather tedious and ineffective. Many of the library's components are needed in every page.

How can I instead import all (or most) of the library's components and be able to use them in *any* file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just want a simple one-line import for everything in Smelte and you don't give a hoot about tree-shaking you can always `import * as Smelte from 'smelte'` in your script tag substituting `Smelte` for whatever you want the component tag modifier to be.

In order to use the components you need to use the modifier like so `<Smelte.Button>`

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d8d0e53fd86b496eb63b177408290708?version=3.23.2) showing it off (minus the Smelte styling).

However, if you want to only import some as a single statement you can do a similar trick and only export the ones you need from a separate JS file. There's plenty of ways to export it but the following would be one:

```
// somefile.js
import Button from "smelte/src/components/Button"
import Treeview from "smelte/src/components/Treeview"

export {
  Button,
  Treeview
}
```

Then inside your Svelte files you can `import * as Smelte from './somefile.js'` and access those components in the same way as the first method.

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2d569667f6fc477e98917f82eba78b92?version=3.23.2) for that as well.

Pretty sure both ways would present some treeshaking complications but your script tags will be less cluttered and you won't have to worry about importing every single part you need.

Comment: I don't use SCSS anymore so I can't speak to that directly but I do use Post CSS which requires preprocessing. I use [this package](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess) and it works like a charm. Prior to finding that I tried with rollup-plugin-postcss and couldn't get it to work.

Give svelte-preprocess a shot and see if that does the trick for your SCSS issue. [here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFeJKQdzzvo) of someone integrating SASS might be similar, good luck!